# Setting up a custom workflow for the model change-form view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

### Context

I have a model, let's call it `Application`.

```
class Application(models.Model):
    # various fields here

    status = status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=APPLICATION_STATUSES,
        default=PENDING_STATUS[0],
    )

    assigned_operator = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        editable=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

This model has some fields, but the ones we care here are the `status`, which is simply a choice field, and the `assigned_operator` field, which defines a 1-1 relationship with a `User` instance. This model also has its corresponding `ApplicationAdmin` view defined.

### Description

The **requirement** is that when trying to edit an Application, from the admin view, the default workflow, where you make whatever changes you want and then simply save the form, should be replaced with the following workflow:

- The application form is readonly **unless** the user is the `assigned_operator` of the application, in which case the application is editable.
- When the user **is not** the application's `assigned_operator` the actions at the bottom will be 1 button:
- - "Assign to myself" - When clicked the `Application` model is updated to reference the current user as  its `assigned_operator` and the page refreshes
- When the user **is** the application's `assigned_operator` the actions at the bottom will be 3 buttons:
- - "Save changes" - Does what default "Save" button does
- - "Reject" - When clicked changes the `status` field of the application to the appropriate one
- - "Accept" - When clicked changes the `status` field of the application to the appropriate one

### The problem

Well, the problem is that I am pretty new with django and I am pretty lost here.

**What I know:**

- How to make the fields of the form editable or read only based on the `assigned_operator` value. I think I just have to set up a `get_readonly_fields` and do my checks there. Correct me if wrong.
- I can replace the current list of form actions with some custom buttons by adding a `change_form_template = "path/to/change_form.html"` field to the `ApplicationAdmin`. An example `change_form.html` that I have now:

```
{%  extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign to me" class="default" name="????">
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**What I don't know**

- How to conditionally show either the "Assign to myself" or the group-of-3-buttons, depending on the `assigned_operator` value of the `Application` model.
- How to connect those new custom buttons to interact with the models and do stuff on them, when they are clicked
- In general how the `change_form.html` part, which is just a template as far as I know, can know things from the currently displayed model instance and the current user.

**While code examples are welcome, I do not ask you to give me the implementation. Clear directives/instructions will do just fine, I just need some guidance**

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I figured how to pass info to the template, by using the `change_view` method of the `ModelAdmin`. So now I can conditionally display the appropriate buttons.

**UPDATE 2**
Just figured out how to also do something to a model once a button is clicked. We can use either `response_change` or `change_view` for that (not sure which one is the more "correct" option, but both work. Difference is that `change_view` runs before the view is even rendered, while `response_change` runs after the form has been saved and the model updated)

Comment: Do you need to use the admin for this? It would be easier using a custom view. The django admin isn't known for its extensibility.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be part of the administrative part of the application, so it needs to happen in `admin`. Unless I am not understanding what you suggest, which is very possible.

Comment: It's possible but not pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to conditionally show either the "Assign to myself" or the group-of-3-buttons, depending on the assigned_operator value of the Application model.

By overriding the `change_view` method of the `ModelAdmin` in our custom Admin view we can pass extra context to our html templates, as showcased in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view). So now we can conditionally display the appropriate buttons, by adding an `{% if context_value %}` in the template.

> How to connect those new custom buttons to interact with the models and do stuff on them, when they are clicked

We can use either `response_change` or `change_view` for that on our Admin view. In there we can listen for the value of our button's name in the `request.POST` values (for example `_save` etc) and act accordingly

(not sure which one is the more "correct" option to use, the `response_change` or the `change_view` but both work. Difference is that `change_view` runs before the view is even rendered, while `response_change` runs after the form has been saved and the model updated)

> In general how the change_form.html part, which is just a template as far as I know, can know things from the currently displayed model instance and the current user.

A combination of passing it context from the Admin view and listening for button names from the template in the `request.POST`